# How do I search according to fields in inner classes using MongoDB db.coll.find()?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, database

I am trying to find the documents in the my collection using find() command in MongoDB,
can anybody explain why it doesn't work? and correct command to execute the same ?

```
j = {name:"mongo",property:{type:"database",lang:"cpp"}};
{
    "name" : "mongo",
    "property" : {
        "type" : "database",
        "lang" : "cpp"
    }
}

db.dummy.save(j);

db.dummy.find({"property" : { "type" : "database" }});
```

The last command deosn't return anything to me. I am not able to understand why. What do I do if I

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mongodb there is concept of [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29). So to reach into embedded documents you should use dot notation. In your case it will looks like:

```
db.dummy.find({"property.type": "database"})
```

Or you can search by full object match like this:

```
db.dummy.find({"property" : { "type" : "database", "lang" : "cpp" }});
```

Answer (score 1):

correct query pattern is this:

```
db.dummy.find({"property.type": "database"})
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works:

```
db.dummy.find({"property.type": "database"})
```